# Problema com a SplashScreen no IONIC

Tags: javascript, java, apache-cordova, ubuntu, ionic

alguém já teve algum erro parecido com este da imagem ao tentar dar o Build na aplicação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu achava que era o plugin da SpalshScreen que é instalado automaticamente... Atualizei.. Não resolveu... Achei que fosse a versão do Java. Também não resolveu...
Alguém pode me ajudar?
A aplicação funciona normal, só não aparece a SplashScreen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução dada por um membro do grupo Ionic Brasil **Evandro Oliveira** no [facebook](https://web.facebook.com/groups/1558333777738228/permalink/1687990901439181/?comment_id=1688174978087440&reply_comment_id=1688329404738664&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D)

> A splashscreen aparecer preto é um bug nesta última versão do cordova 6... tive isso... roda os seguintes comandos para remover o atual e adicionar o mais atualizado corrigindo esse bug:
>
> ```
> ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
>
> ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
> ```